# Update para limpar coluna inteira

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

Preciso fazer um `update` no banco em que zere 30 mil registros, porém eu preciso zerar apenas o registro de uma das colunas.

Exemplo tabela: cd_produto|ds_produto|pr_produto|dt_atualizacao

Essa tabela contém os 30mil registros e eu preciso zerar todas as `dt_atualizacao`, mas apenas ela, as outras colunas não podem ser alteradas.

Como posso montar esse `update`?

Comment: Tem alguma coisa que você não está dizendo? Pergunto isto porque é algo extramente trivial fazer isto. Esta coluna é de que tipo? DATE? Você quer que seja nulo ou que valor?

Comment: O motivo é que existe uma nova rotina que lê essa tabela e para cada linha sem a dt_atualização será inserido uma nova informação cd_grupo. A rotina já está pronta e agora só preciso limpar todas as dt_atualização para que a rotina funcione. A coluna é do tipo DATETIME e eu preciso que esteja vazio.

Comment: O que é zerar? Que valor deve ter?

Comment: Perdão a confusão, é para ser nulo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seria algo bem trivial anular se for possível e desejável:

```
UPDATE tabela SET dt_atualizacao = null;
```

Ou colocar um valor bem baixo:

```
UPDATE tabela SET dt_atualizacao = TO_DATE('0000-01-01 00:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss');
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Update/ClearColumn.sql).

Comment: Não achei que fosse tão simples, obrigado !

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE TABELA SET DT_ATUALIZACAO = NULL
```

Mas atente:

1) Existem *triggers* nesta tabela , o `update` gera alguma demanda por conta desta operação ? Log etc

2) Existe espaço para a trilha de *audit* do Banco?

A dúvida "assusta" pois é uma operação trivial como disse o @Maniero e pode mascarar algum outro problema.

Comment: Entendo que possa ser trivial e até perigoso uma operação dessas. Só estou realizando ela para que a nova informação pedida pelo cliente seja inserida através da nova rotina que olha a dt_atualizacao vazia. Obrigado pela ajuda.